# Is there a way to use wildcards with git checkout?

Tags: git, wildcard, git-checkout

What I would like to do is to checkout a single file or a set of files with a common name part like this

`git checkout myBranch */myFile.md` and

`git checkout myBranch -- */*Test*` (not sure about the '--' part)

instead of

`git checkout myBranch src/main/java/a/deep/package/structure/myFile.md` and

`git checkout myBranch src/test/java/a/deep/package/structure/TestOne.java`
 
`git checkout myBranch src/test/java/a/deep/package/structure/TestTwo.java`
 
`git checkout myBranch src/test/java/a/deep/package/structure/resources/TestData.sql`

I know there is some limited wildcard functionality for some git command like `diff` and `add` but have found nothing for `checkout`. Is there a way?

EDIT: I am using git 1.7.9.5 on Linux. A working combination of git and shell commmands would be acceptable as well.

Comment: Strange, `git diff` doesn't seem to support wildcards for me, though `git add` and `commit` do.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Git **does** deal with wildcards, using [fnmatch(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html). See the *pathspec* entry in [Git glossary](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary.html#def_pathspec).

But to be sure that git can see the wildcards, they must be escaped otherwise your *shell* will expand them first. Typically, I use wildcards between single-quotes:

```
git checkout myBranch -- '*/myFile.md'
```

The wildcards are applied to the whole name, directories included.

As you can see in the documentation, the pathspec also allows *magic signature* which change how to interpret the pathspec. For example, you can have case-insensitive paths with *icase* (you can type `':(icase)*readme*'` to find all your readme's).

I quote @bambams's comment here, in case you have problems in Windows:

> This is not working for me in Windows with 2.8.1.windows.1 and I'm
>   utilizing Git from the cmd.exe shell so no globbing built in. There is
>   however a solution if you're in such a sorry state. Combine `git diff --name-only` and `xargs` to achieve your goal:
>
> ```
> git diff --name-only <COMMIT> -- <GLOB>... | xargs git checkout <COMMIT>
> ```

Comment: A bit late to the party but undoubtedly correct. Thanks @coredump, time to move the green checkmark :)

Comment: @kostja Yes, definitely late ;-) Thanks

Comment: But no way to wildcard the branch name, e.g. `git checkout my*`?

Comment: This is not working for me in Windows with 2.8.1.windows.1 and I'm utilizing Git from the cmd.exe shell so no globbing built in. There is however a solution if you're in such a sorry state. Combine git diff --name-only and xargs to achieve your goal: `git diff --name-only <COMMIT> -- <GLOB>... | xargs git checkout <COMMIT> --`

Comment: Git v2.13.2.windows.1 didn't want the escape apostrophe, `git checkout */myFile.md` worked fine and went through subfolders.

Comment: On windows, @bambams has a great workaround, but I didn't have `xargs` on my path. Recent Git versions have this and many other Linux utils in `\<path to Git>\usr\bin` so I add that to my path and I'm all set.

Answer (score 25):

Git does not deal with the wildcard, but your shell does.

Try this :

```
git checkout myBranch **/myFile.md
```

and

```
git checkout myBranch  **/*Test*
```

With the `**`, your shell will look for files in all the subdirectories starting from the current working directory.

Comment: Works as advertised. Thank you Intrepidd

Comment: Note that this _only_ considers files that the shell sees, e.g., checked out files. It does _not_ checkout files that aren't already present.

Comment: @vonbrand: any way to do it with files that are in the commit but not currently in the file system?

Comment: Which shell? I'm using Cygwin bash and this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Dumb question - how can you include all cases of `*Test*` even if the file is in the root?   `**/*Test*` doesn't include files in the root (I believe).

Comment: @MarcusLeon Maybe depends on the shell but I tried with zsh and it works.

Answer (score 2):

**Powershell**

```
@(gci -Recurse *test* | Resolve-Path -Relative) | %{git checkout mybranch -- $_)
```

gci generates a list of all files matching the criteria (`*test*`) then pipes it to Resolve-Path to get the relative path. Finally the flattened (@) list of filenames is piped into the git invokation (executes once per file found).

Answer (score 2):

Windows git bash with xargs

```
git difftool myBranch --name-only *.java | xargs git checkout myBranch
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me, but bambams comment worked. I made it into a bash function that accepts two args.
Usage:

gitcheckout myBranch '*file*'

```
gitcheckout()
{
    GIT_DIR=$(git rev-parse --git-dir 2>/dev/null); 
    pushd .;
    cd $GIT_DIR/../;
    git diff --name-only $1 -- $2 | xargs git checkout $1 --;
    popd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a gitignore or untracked files and you want to use wildcards with git checkout, then it might give you problems, and a solution could be:

```
git ls-files '*/myFile.md' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -L1 -I '$' git checkout -- '$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that git returns branch list names from 3rd char, one can just switch to needed branch defined via [mask]:

```
BRANCH_NAME=$(git branch --list | grep [mask] | cut -c3-)
git checkout ${BRANCH_NAME}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the task was to checkout several files named after one pattern:

- `./a/b/c/FirstTest.java`
- `.d/e/f/SecondTest.java`
- `./g/h/i/ThirdTest.java`

I've used this bash command:

```bash
# 1. Find files named after "*Test.java" pattern.
# 2. Execute checkout command on every found file.

find . -name "*Test.java" -exec git checkout master {} \;
```

Also firstly you can test the `find` command with simple `echo`, which just prints a given text (`{}` in our case, which will be replaced with current found filename by shell):

```bash
find . -name "*Test.java" -exec echo {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the files from a commit regardless of whether they were changed in that commit, you can use the following:

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r myBranch | grep myFilePattern | xargs git checkout myBranch
```