# How to git checkout all files from another branch matching a specific pattern?

Tags: bash, git

I'd like to copy all files from another git branch matching a certain pattern.

Comment: You mean, files that match a given pattern? Like '*.js'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to use wildcards with git checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160978/is-there-a-way-to-use-wildcards-with-git-checkout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you need all js files in all directories. That could be done like this:

```
git checkout the-other-branch -- '*/*.js'
```

That will put all those files on the working tree *and* also on the index ready to be committed, with *no* relation to the branch that you are checking out from... your branch pointer doesn't move.

Comment: Your solution would work for **way** more complex patterns. What I'd probably skip is the while read.... I think it's much better to use an xargs: `git ls-tree -r --name-only <branch> | grep <pattern> | xargs git checkout <branch> --`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve using a bash command i created. First `git checkout` the branch you wish to copy to then run the following command:

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only <branch> | grep <pattern> | while read line; do git checkout <branch> -- $line; done
```

First this lists all files in the source branches directory using `git-ls-tree` then uses `grep` to filter only for files that match the Pattern. Then using a while loop reads each line and copys the file across using `git checkout`.

Comment: I think `while read line; do git checkout <branch> -- $line; done` could be replaced with `xargs git checkout <branch> -- `; this is also a bit faster.